# Make: how to continue after a command fails?

Tags: makefile

The command `$ make all` gives errors such as `rm: cannot remove '.lambda': No such file or directory` so it stops. I want it to ignore the rm-not-found-errors. How can I force-make?

**Makefile**

```
all:
        make clean
        make .lambda
        make .lambda_t
        make .activity
        make .activity_t_lambda
clean:
        rm .lambda .lambda_t .activity .activity_t_lambda

.lambda:
        awk '{printf "%.4f \n", log(2)/log(2.71828183)/$$1}' t_year > .lambda

.lambda_t:
        paste .lambda t_year > .lambda_t

.activity:
        awk '{printf "%.4f \n", $$1*2.71828183^(-$$1*$$2)}' .lambda_t > .activity

.activity_t_lambda:
        paste .activity t_year .lambda  | sed -e 's@\t@\t\&\t@g' -e 's@$$@\t\\\\@g' | tee > .activity_t_lambda > ../RESULTS/currentActivity.tex
```

Answer (score 387, accepted):

Try the `-i` flag (or `--ignore-errors`). [The documentation](http://www.ipp.mpg.de/~dpc/gmake/make_47.html) seems to suggest a more robust way to achieve this, by the way:

> To ignore errors in a command line, write a `-` at the beginning of the line's text (after the initial tab). The `-` is discarded before the command is passed to the shell for execution.
>
> For example,
>
> ```
> clean:
>   -rm -f *.o
> ```
>
> This causes `rm` to continue even if it is unable to remove a file.

All examples are with `rm`, but are applicable to any other command you need to ignore errors from (i.e. `mkdir`).

Comment: Don't *do* that! You shouldn't ignore errors. Just add the -f flag to rm and it'll no longer fail when trying to delete files which don't exist. It will however still return and error if it really fails to delete a file. That's the behaviour you want, fail when there's a problem!

Comment: @Kristof Provost Agreed. `rm -f` is better for the specific problem the user is having, but it's still nice to know about the general solution even if it's sometimes unsafe.

Comment: Make also provides `$(RM)`, which you can use instead of `rm -f`.

Comment: Just noting there *are* cases where it's legitimate to ignore the error code: for example, a make rule which for informative purposes shows a diff against a previous version.  Standard `diff(1)` returns 1 for files which differ, so you might want an action like `-diff -N $@.prev $@`.  However, as this will still give you a warning (gnu make), you might prefer `diff -N $@.prev $@ || true`, which is quieter, though does look ugly.

Answer (score 70):

`make -k` (or `--keep-going` on gnumake) will do what you are asking for, I think.

You really ought to find the del or rm line that is failing and add a `-f` to it to keep that error from happening to others though.

Comment: I didn't want to say anything, but I was wondering what their thinking was too. If there's some reason I don't see why that flag would not be appropriate, it would be a good thing to bring up.

Comment: You shouldn't ignore errors. The solution proposed by Brian, Oded and NebuSoft are correct. This one and the accepted answer are wrong.

Comment: @KristofProvost - Ah. Fair enough I guess. Generally I also believe answers that get at the root of the problem are superior to ones (like this one) that meerly answer the asked question. I'm not sure I'd *downvote* somebody for that, but different strokes...

Comment: Nice answer. It contains a straightforward, top-level flag which no other answer contains, yet still recommends the correct behavior. Errors shouldn't be ignored, but it's good to know the options.

Comment: Something useful to do is to ignore compiler errors... which allows `make` to build as many compilation units as possible while you go fix whatever the compiler choked on. That way when you've fixed whatever was broken, you don't have to wait for everything else to build too.

Comment: @KristofProvost Another valid reason for wanting this is when you use make to run tests or deploy or other automation. Make is not *just* for compiling. So knowing the options is fine.

Comment: This is a safer answer than using the `-i` flag because instead of outright ignoring errors, which can cause other issues down the road, the `-k` flag merely tells make to build all targets that it can even though one failed. It might be worth adding some more explanation of the `-k` and the `-i` flags in the answer.

Answer (score 63):

Return successfully by blocking `rm`'s returncode behind a pipe with the `true` command, which always returns `0` (success)

```
rm file || true
```

Comment: You can also use `rm file || true`.


That way `true` is called if `rm` returns an error code.  But any console output from `rm` might produce is not swallowed by the pipe.

Comment: I would even say that you *should* use ` || true` when your *real intent* is not to pipe `stdout`.

Comment: I imagine this was a typo all along. Since this is a canonical for this question and this answer is highly upvoted, I fixed the typo to recommend the correct and idiomatic usage over the confused and accidental (but in fact coincidentally working) original code.

Comment: I prefer `find ... -delete` if `rm -f` is a bad idea

Answer (score 24):

Change clean to

```
rm -f .lambda .lambda_t .activity .activity_t_lambda
```

I.e. don't prompt for remove; don't complain if file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 19):

To get make to actually ignore errors on a single line, you can simply suffix it with `; true`, setting the return value to 0.  For example:

```
rm .lambda .lambda_t .activity .activity_t_lambda 2>/dev/null; true
```

This will redirect stderr output to null, and follow the command with true (which always returns 0, causing make to believe the command succeeded regardless of what actually happened), allowing program flow to continue.

Comment: This works for me where the leading dash does not (I'm given a makefile to run a test which needs to fail, and will parse the logs later)

Answer (score 4):

Put an `-f` option in your `rm` command.

```
rm -f .lambda .lambda_t .activity .activity_t_lambda
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your `clean` so `rm` will not complain:

```
clean:
    rm -f .lambda .lambda_t .activity .activity_t_lambda
```

Answer (score 3):

Usage of `-` seems to be a proper way of handling such situations as it can ignore the error of a specific command, but not all errors.

You can find more information by the following [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Errors).

Comment: This basically repeats the accepted answer, though it presents this rather obscurely.