# Time Variables in Bash Scripting

Tags: bash, variables, time, scripting

If I have 3 different scripts to run at various times each time a file is written to, how would a bash script be written to run a specific script only at a specific time. This is not as simple as a cron job (though cron could probably swap out the .sh file based on time), I am looking for the time variables.

For instance:

```
If 9am-11:30 am run scriptA.sh if file.txt is changed. 
If 11:30am-5:45pm run scriptB.sh if file is changed.
If 5:46pm-8:59am run scriptC.sh if file is changed.
```

I asked a similar question but I don't think I was clear enough about the variables I am seeking or how to define them..

Comment: You might be able to do something with `date` and its formatting, turning timestamps into minutes of day. E.g. `$(date +"%H") * 60 + $(date +"%S")`. (The multiplication and addition are not proper bash, rather symbolic.)

Comment: But I think your cron job, with a fourth script that's just a symlink to the current relevant script, is not a bad idea at all.

Comment: What does "is changed" mean?  Is changed since when?

Comment: Meaning the file in question was last modified or accessed. I already have figured that part out though, thanks. Just working on understanding the time stuff. :)

Comment: I would have changed the symlink target for `script.sh` to be `scriptA/B/C.sh` using 3 `cron` jobs. Will that not be simpler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The traditional tool for comparing time stamps to determine whether work needs to be performed or not is `make`.  Its default behavior is to calculate a dependency chain for the specified target(s) and determine whether any of the dependent files have changed; if not, the target does not need to be remade.  This is a great tool for avoiding recompilation, but it easily extends to other tasks.

In concrete terms, you'd create a flag file (say, `.made`) and specify it as dependent on your `file`.  Now, if `file` has changed, `.made` needs to be recreated, and so `make` will run the commands you specify to do so.  In this scenario, we would run a simple piece of shell script, then `touch .made` to communicate the latest (successful) run time to future runs.

What remains is for the recipe to run different commands at different times.  My approach to that would be a simple `case` statement.  Notice that `make` interprets dollar signs, so we need to double those dollar signs which should be passed through to the shell.

```
.made: file
    case $$(date +%H:%M) in \
        09:* | 10:* | 11:[0-2]? ) \
            scriptA.sh ;; \
        11:[3-5]? | 1[2-6]:* | 17:[0-3]? | 17:4[0-5]) \
            scriptB.sh;; \
        17:4[6-9] | 17:5? | 1[89]:* | 2?:* | 0[0-8]:* ) \
            scriptC.sh;; \
    esac
    touch $@   # $@ expands to the current target
```

The entire `case` statement needs to be passed as a single logical line to the shell, so we end up with those pesky backslashes to escape the newlines.

Also notice that `make` is picky about indentation; each (logical) line in the recipe should be preceded by a literal tab character.

The default behavior of `make` is to run the first target in the file; this `Makefile` only contains one target, so `make` is equivalent to `make .made`.

Also notice that `make` cares about exit codes; if `scriptA`, `scriptB`, or `scriptC` could exit with a non-zero exit status, that is regarded by `make` as a fatal error, and the `.made` file will not be updated.  (You can easily [guard against this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670130/make-how-to-continue-after-a-command-fails), though.)

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much! You have given me a goldmine to study. I only understand about 60% of it at this moment, as I am barely past the Hello World with bash, but I had no idea that it could be that powerful. Are you accepting new clients? I don't complain and I am not picky or demanding. ;)

Comment: Not really; I am fully employed.  If you are serious about this, you need another 10 reputation points and then we can [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Absolutely, I am obviously in way over my head. I have an idea of the pieces of the puzzle needed to get the complete package functional enough to be happy, but no idea how to get them. It is such a mess right now everything hacked and duct taped together for basic functionality... Thank you again for all the help and advice. Talk to you in a couple days if I don't get kicked off here for my questions first. :)

Answer (score 2):

I see there are two issues. 1, how to determine if the current hour is within a particular range. 2, how to determine if a file has been modified, recently.

Here's how I would approach that:

```
#!/bin/bash

now=$( date +%s )
current_hour=$( date +%H )
file_mod=$( ls -l --time-style=+%s file.txt | awk '{print $(NF-1)}' )
file_age=$(( $now - $file_mod ))

if [[ $current_hour -gt 9 ]] && \
   [[ $current_hour -lt 11 ]] && \
   [[ $file_age -lt 3600 ]]
then
    ./scriptA.sh
fi
```

Here I'm using the bash operators for numeric comparison: -gt, -lt

For greater granularity with time, you would need to compute the amount of time since midnight.  Perhaps something like:

```
hour=$( date +%H )
min=$( date +%M )
minutes=$( echo "( 60 * $hour ) + $min" | bc -l )

eleven_thirty=$( echo "( 60 * 11 ) + 30" | bc -l )
```

Comment: Excellent help! Let's say we take out the complexity of the file modification... If I manually run the script and just focus on the time aspect needing sorted. When you say greater granularity, by this you mean that your first snippet of code is a two hour window and that 11:30 is not calculated, merely the 11th hour correct?

Comment: Yes, you would need to express 11:30 AM in terms of minutes since midnight.

Comment: You could replace `ls` with `stat`, but unfortunately, the details of how to get a time stamp out of that aren't portable, either. For portability, maybe write a simple Perl replacement.

Comment: I would put the file age as a simple outer condition, and then do a `case` statement on the current time.

Comment: I am not a developer, can you describe what you mean by portability? Do you mean for use outside of this little script? Thank you for the feedback, I really am trying to take this all in.

Comment: The `--time-style` option to `ls` is not supported e.g. on Mac OSX; it is a GNU `coreutils` extension.  If you need your script to run on non-Linux platforms, you need a solution which doesn't rely on this particular implementation.  That's what's meant by portability.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since Bash variables can store `string` or `integer` only, 
"date" variables are just a string manipulations, like example below:

```
hours=`date +%H`
minutes=`date +%M`
sum=$(($hours + $minutes))
digit=`echo $sum | sed -e 's/\(^.*\)\(.$\)/\2/'` # counts total digits
```