# Makefile: Run multiple targets

Tags: linux, makefile

I would like to run two targets using a makefile but don't know how to specify the targets from the command line.

This is my makefile.

```
.PHONY: all clean test
PYTHON=python
PYTESTS=pytest

all:
    $(PYTHON) setup.py build_ext --inplace

clean:
    find . -name "*.so" -o -name "*.pyc" -o -name "*.md5" -o -name "*.pyd" | xargs rm -f
    find . -name "*.pyx" -exec ./tools/rm_pyx_c_file.sh {} \;

benchmark_coverage:
    $(PYTESTS) benchmarks --cov=skimage

coverage: test_coverage

test_coverage:
    $(PYTESTS) -o python_functions=test_* skimage --cov=skimage
```

So, I'm mainly interested in `coverage`, `benchmark_coverage` and `test_coverage`.

When I run the command `make coverage`, it runs
`$(PYTESTS) -o python_functions=test_* skimage --cov=skimage`.

When I run `make bench_coverage`, it runs 
`$(PYTESTS) benchmarks --cov=skimage`.

Now, I want to run both of these together, how do I do this?

Someone suggested me `make coverage bench_coverage` but it only runs the first command.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Definitely, that can be done and I did that. I was just curious to know if there is way by which this can be done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried creating the following Makefile:

```
a:
   echo a

b:
   echo b
```

and if I run `make a b` it  runs both, so running multiple targets actually is allowed.

Comment: oh, my bad. Thanks @Bitwise. The first command resulted in an error. That's why it didn't run the second one. I changed the order and both of them ran. Can I do something in the case when one command fails? I want the others to run.

Comment: @AbhishekArya see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670130/make-how-to-continue-after-a-command-fails

Comment: Used `--keep-going` flag

Comment: tip: this (supplying multiple targets) works with pattern matching (i.e. `%`, and `$@`) with different inputs too. 

aside, same happened with me too, make encountered a fatal error (i.e. the error log starting with ***) with first target lol